# jQuery - Serialize Array of Inputs

Tags: php, jquery, serialization

I'm missing something in my code.  I have a list of text boxes that are meant for percentage values, and there could be numerous inputs.

```
// loop through unknown inputs with different values
<input name="DESIREDPERCENT[<?php echo $recid; ?>]" class="percinputbox" />
// end loop

// attach click event to this element
<span id="updatepercs">Update Percentages</span>
```

I then have a simple span element to send all the inputs with the class `percinputbox`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#updatepercs').click(function(){
   var allinputs = $("input.percinputbox").serialize();
   console.log(allinputs);  //DESIREDPERCENT%5B73%5D=50.00&DESIREDPERCENT%5B104%5D=50.00    

   $.ajax({
     url:'update.php',
     data:"formId=updatepercentages" + allinputs,
     success:function(response){ alert(response); } 
  }); 

});
```

I have my `php` listening for the `$.ajax`:

update.php

```
<?php
if($_POST['formId'] == 'updatepercentages'){
  foreach( $_REQUEST['DESIREDPERCENT'] as $key ){
    echo $key;
  }
}
?>
```

So far I'm only getting one input value.  So I'm definitely doing the sending wrong.

I'm open to a better/optimized way here.  I generally use the `<form>` tag to submit forms, but I want to know how to submit these inputs with `jquery`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an `&` between `formId=updatepercentages` and `allinputs`

`data:"formId=updatepercentages&" + allinputs,`

Comment: Mother Of Pearl!!  I knew it was something mundane!